# Getting "Chrome not reachable" error while executing test scripts in Selenium Grid With Chrome browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am running the automation test script in selenium Grid with chrome browser and I am getting `Chrome not reachable` error.

```
 cucumber.runtime.CucumberException:
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
 chrome not reachable
      (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.84)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your platform is Linux. Can you please add below capabilities along with your existing one in case not done already and let us know.

```
ChromeOptions cOptions = new ChromeOptions();
//argument to switch off suid sandBox and no sandBox in Chrome 
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox");
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox");
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I am using the below function in my application.                             if (strBrowser.equals("grid")) {
               DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                tLog.logInfo("Chrome called on Selenium Grid")
                cap.setCapability("platform", "LINUX");
                cap.setCapability("version","68.0.3440.84");
                wdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("hub url "), cap);
                wdriver.get(strCapAppPathName);
                wdriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600)); }

Comment: Did u trying adding mentioned above along with yours

Comment: Did u check is chrome installed on linux

Comment: Yes. it is installed